# How to get an image when you click on text in a table

Tags: javascript

In javascript I created a table and now i when i click on data inside the table I want an image to appear. I am new to coding so somehow i am unable to figure out a solution to this problem.
[This is my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCJSf.png) I would like to add an image when someone clicks on data inside the webpage and then an image should show up next to the names column

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>My homepage</title>
<style>
body { background-color: coral;
  font-family: vernada;
}
table { border: 3px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
}
div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 200px;
  display: none;
}
td, th { border: 3px solid white;
  font-family: helvetta;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color:blue;
}
tr:hover {
 background-color:gray;
}
span:hover + div {
  display: block;
</style>
<body>
        Employee First Name:<input type="text" name="efname" id="fname"><br><br>
        Employee Last Name:<input type="text" name="elname" id="lname"><br><br>
        Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br><br>
<table id = "table">
<tr>
<th>Employee First Name</th>
<th>Employee Last Name</th>
<th> age</th>
</tr>
<span>
<tr>
<div> Leo Dicaprio is 50 years old </div>
<td>Leo</td>
<td>DiCaprio</td>
<td>50</td>
</tr>
</span>
<span>
<tr>
<div> Jill smith is 50 years old </div>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
</span>
<span>
  <tr>
<div> Eve jackson is 94 years old</div>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</span>
<span>
  <tr>
    <div> John Doe is 80 years old</div>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</span>
</table>
<button onclick="myfunction()">Add data</button>
<input type = "image" src = addimage()>
  <script>

                var table = document.getElementById('table');

                for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                    {

                         document.getElementById("fname").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementById("lname").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                         document.getElementById("age").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                    }
                }



function myfunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 cell1.innerHTML=(document.getElementById("fname").value);
 cell2.innerHTML=(document.getElementById("lname").value);
 cell3.innerHTML=(document.getElementById("age").value);
}


         </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Have a look at this article on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately your "question" is well below the standard required on this site. Please have a look at the [help] and in particular the [ask] pages

Comment: sounds like you might need CSS selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) and Event Listeners (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener).